# Tableau data blending issue

Tags: database, tableau-api

Hello Tableau community,

i would to ask about blending because i am facing a lot of issues.

More specifically i have two tables:
1)The first one Which i story the `countries` in `2` columns(`country id INT` & `country name STRING`)

2)second table where i keep the `customer data` including (`country id INT` & `id of user`)

My plan is to present visually how much users i have per country by counting the `id of user`,but i can't do the mapping of the country id's

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Do you need help blending, joining, or creating a map?

Comment: @SamM, i would like help with blending & joining these 2.

Comment: Blending and joining are two different things in Tableau and are many times mutually exclusive. It sounds like you may need a tutorial for how to use the product. The Tableau website has some great tutorial clips available. One that will show you how to join tables is found at https://www.tableau.com/about/blog/2016/7/integrate-your-data-cross-database-joins-56724.

Comment: Learn how joins work first. They are the most common solution. Blends are useful also, but less commonly needed - and a bit more complex.

Comment: BTW, there are 2 and 3 digit ISO country codes that Tableau understands. If you use standard country codes, then you may not even need your first table.

Answer (score 0):

First you use inner joins instead of blending so that you will have one final data source. After that change the type country name from string to Geographical role (Country/Region) in the data source tab. After you will be good to plot the data